# navbar bootstrap 3 not work it is displayed in several lines

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i tried to create bootstrap navbar but it displays in two line.
also if I used phone it displays in several lines

i tried to create bootstrap navbar but it displays in two line.
also if I used phone it displays in several lines

i tried to create bootstrap navbar but it displays in two line.
also if I used phone it displays in several lines

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  

  <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="{{url('users/'.$users->id.'/edit')}}">image de converture</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{url('users/'.$users->id.'/edit')}}">image de profile </a></li>
            <li><a href="{{url('users/'.$users->id.'/edit')}}">mes images</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{url('users/'.$users->id.'/edit')}}">mes infomation</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav> 
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `<li>` should have class `.nav-item`

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="{{url('users/'.$users->id.'/edit')}}">image de converture</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="{{url('users/'.$users->id.'/edit')}}">image de profile </a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="{{url('users/'.$users->id.'/edit')}}">mes images</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="{{url('users/'.$users->id.'/edit')}}">mes infomation</a></li>
          </ul>
```

Comment: thx for u answer but when i used phone it displays in several lines

Answer (score 0):

As @Igor Nowosad said, and add the class `nav-link` to your `<a></a>`. You can also remove `nav` class from your `<ul></ul>`.

Additionally, do not forget that Bootstrap is built for **responsiveness**, so if your elements are too big, it will change the display to fit your window. So inline elements could be displayed vertically.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{url('users/'.$users->id.'/edit')}}">image de converture</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{url('users/'.$users->id.'/edit')}}">image de profile </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{url('users/'.$users->id.'/edit')}}">mes images</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{url('users/'.$users->id.'/edit')}}">mes infomation</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Otherelse, have a look at
[List-group bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/list-group/)
You also can fix the display depending on sizes breakpoints `xs, sm, md, lg, xl` by suffixing the class `list-group-horizontal-{breakpoint_suffix}`